# Excel Dynamic Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dynamic Spreadsheet with these columns.

Subject | ID | Status | Assigned To | Created By | Created On | Date Closed

I am trying to create a formula that can count:

- Count all where status=Completed and Date is this year.
- Count all records that were created today

I tried multiple formulas but I am not sure why its not working, I am not able to filter properly to get the correct records. Any help would be beneficial.

I tried `=COUNTIFS(B:B, "Completed", H:H, ">=01/01/2018")` But this did not filter the record.It still includes records from previous years.

I also tried two separate count if statements. Those those did not seem to work either.

Comment: Try COUNTIFS or COUNTIF.

Comment: I Tried COUNTIF and COUNTIFS. I attempted

=COUNTIFS(B:B, "Completed", H:H, ">=01/01/2018") 

But this does not filter the record. It just gives 0. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: I added more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula seems fine. Just check and make sure the date format is correct. You can also add a separate column for **year** (you can use `year` function) and write `=COUNTIFS(B:B, "Completed", I:I, 2018)`. (I guess your code doesn't run because **Excel** considers your given date as text and not a true date!

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that your H:H is a date format but not text, you may try to use the integer equivalent of 01/01/2018 in yor formula, which is 43101. So your formula would be:

`=COUNTIFS(B:B, "Completed", H:H, ">=" & 43101)`

Or you may write your limit date to a cell and may directly reference that cell in your formula:

`=COUNTIFS(B:B, "Completed", H:H, ">=" & E7)`